# Safest way to see if a user is still "logged in" (REST API)

Tags: rest-api, security, permissions, oauth2, oauth

I'm using the Salesforce REST API along with [OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en_US). I have the need to "ping" Salesforce to see if a user is logged on (this is the simplest way to do so in my application). If the result returns a 401 status code, I know I need to log them back on.

The "ping" is a simple SOQL request: `select id from account limit 1`

I'm concerned that there may be a case where a user does not have access to query the Account object, and therefore the query may fail. Is there a object query, metadata request, etc I could perform that is always guaranteed accessible to the user, regardless of permission settings? (i.e. some universal object that the user has to be able to read)

*Salesforce version 31.0*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could request one of the more basic REST resources, such as [Versions](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_versions.htm) or [Limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_limits.htm).

If they have API access then there will always be a resource for a valid Session.

Comment: i did some testing and `/services/data/v50.0/limits` counts towards rest request limits (ironically) `/services/data/` doesn't seem to

Answer (score 1):

If want to avoid the "ping" counting towards the `API Requests` limit, you may be able to use:

`/services/oauth2/userinfo`

In [this related answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/229685/3341), the author tested and confirmed it doesn't count towards the limit.

This endpoint may only be available via oAuth generated tokens with the proper scope.