# Login limit exceeded error for an integration user

Tags: integration, oauth2, user, connected-apps

**Background** -  One of the external application (in Java) calls Salesforce resources. Integration user generates OAUTH token through Username-Password flow and uses it to access SF resources. In salesforce ,it shows this user is exceeding the login limit of 3600 per user per hour. However, in the log of the external application it shows , user logs in very less around 100 times per hour.

**Investigation so far**  - I looked into the connected app ,configuration looks fine.However in the connected app OAUTH usage - Integration user doesn't appear for that connected app. Also on the user record,  related record - 'Oauth connected app' doesn't show the connected app name. 
I tried with refresh token flow , instead of username-password, then it seems to be working fine.

**Question** - 1) Why connected app name doesn't appear for that user record OR neither user name appears at the OAUTH usage of the connected app ? Though Username - Password flow uses client id and secret from that connected app. Why its working for refresh token and web server flow.

2)Will it be fair to say in above case, integration user is not using the connected app? Though it's using it's client id and client secret.

3) Does my login limit issue seem to be related with above? (Integration user not using connected app)

**EDIT 1 - To add more context**

All the calls to the Salesforce are routed through certain proxy servers.

In the Login history, login type shows - Remote Access 2.0 , and under Application it shows the connected app name. But still, OAUTH Usage in the connected app , doesn't show this user in the list.

4) Can these many calls be happening from the intermediate routing/proxy server?

Lastly, I am trying to understand and fix why SF login events shows such a huge number of login per hour, but external application log shows very few logins to SF?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks! In addition to the referenced Q&A above, take a look at this [Login Limit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295340/salesforce-api-login-limit-issue) question

Comment: Since all these questions are connected and have very similar context, that's why put it in a single question, rather than explaining same background and context in 3 different questions. The link of the question you shared was asked by me. It's heading is misleading , there I asked about total API limit. Though answer has 'login  limit' points as well. It doesn't answer the issue , I am facing currently.

Comment: As the referenced answer explains, the User record may not reflect all of oAuth usage but there are other, more definite ways to see login history. This forum prefers a single, crisply defined question to avoid an open-ended discussion and/or vague answers. Please see [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Comment: @identigral - Added some more context to the original question.

Comment: It sounds like you have all the information you need to make progress on your side. Login History is the master record, User is not. The rest is tracing calls from your app(s) to SF and figuring out what component is doing what and how often.