# Login Rate Exceeded - external service calls Salesforce using client_credentials

Tags: rest, oauth2

**Introduction:**
We have an external Java service that communicates with Salesforce instance.
There is a connection using OAuth2.0 client_credentials. For this purpose we have created connected app.

**Use Case:**
We have bulk operation that runs every evening. This operation produces few thousand API Calls to Salesforce system (not possible to separate them - it is event-based and there are several reason for that).

**Problem**
I have checked User login's history and we fall into the limit:

- Login Type: Remote Access 2.0
- Login Subtype: OAuth Client Credentials
- Status: Login Rate Exceeded

We have configured connected app based on the documentation from there:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_client_credentials_setup.htm&type=5

**Question:**
Does it mean that every new REST Api call with this setup to Salesforce produces a new login for related user?
Is there any option to overcome this? Any other suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Salesforce API login limit issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295340/salesforce-api-login-limit-issue)